# JSON PHP what is the correct foreach loop to retrieve this data

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I want to echo only the nickname from this json file, i tried many ways but im really a beginner with json parsing in php.

Here is what i got so far:

```
<?php
$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => "GET",
    'header' => "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\r\n" .
      "accept: application/json\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents('https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/leaderboards/hubs/{hubid}/seasons/12?offset=0&limit=20', false, $context);
$json = json_decode($file, true);
$winners = $json['items'][0]['player']; 
foreach ($winners as $key => $value) 
{
  echo $value['nickname'];
}
```

json example:

```
{
    "leaderboard": {
    },
    "items": [{
            "player": {
                "nickname": "BLABLABLA2",
            },
            "played": 5,
            "won": 4,
        },
                    "player": {
                "nickname": "BLABLABLA2",
            },
            "played": 5,
            "won": 4,
        },
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop was wrong. Some changes in code,

```
$winners = $json['items'];
foreach ($winners as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['player']['nickname'];
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem, finaly.

Answer (score 0):

You catch wrong value in loop.

```
$winners = $json['items'];
foreach ($winners as $index => $value){
  echo $value['player']['nickname'];
}
```